# Wildcard string in notepad++ to replace date format

Tags: notepad++, wildcard

I am struggling to figure out how to replace date format in notepad++
I have a key which contain different dates.

```
<pk2>2014/01/03</pk2>
```

Should be changed to:

```
<pk2>2014-01-03</pk2>
```

and so on.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Get to the Replace, toggle the `Regular expression` option, then Find what: `(\d)\/(\d)`, Replace with: `\1-\2`, then click the `Replace All` button.

Answer (score 2):

This will replace `/` with `-` **only** inside tag `<pk2>...</pk2>`.

Tell me if you want to replace other dates.

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<pk2>|\G(?!^))\d+\K/(?=.*</pk2)`
- Replace with: `-`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    <pk2>           # opening tag pk2
  |               # OR
    \G(?!^)         # restart from last match position if not beginning of line
)               # end group
\d+             # 1 or more digits
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
/               # a slash
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .*              # 0 or more any character but newline
    </pk2           # closing tag
)               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]